# Appcelerator Push Notifications

Tags: iphone, android, mobile, appcelerator

I was wondering if it's possible to create a generic push notification solution for mobile devices (or at least Android and iPhone) with Appcelerator. I found some examples on how to implement iPhone Push with Appcelerator but nothing generic.

Any ideas? Or are there maybe other cross-plattform development sdk to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can use the push notification service with iOS only.
See the [documentation here](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Network.registerForPushNotifications-method.html).

Then, for the iOS, the simpliest way to send/receive notifications, is to subscribe for free for the UrbanAirship service.
You can find a [nice tutorial here](http://urbanairship.com/blog/2010/05/26/appcelerator-and-urban-airship/).

Answer (score 1):

I only know of push notifications working in IOS (for iPhone) too. However, I understand that Cocoafish are soon working on [push notification for Android](http://www.cocoafish.com/docs/api/v1/push_notifications/subscribe). Backends like this and UA are about as generic as you can get.

Answer (score 1):

Using Appcelerator Cloud Service(ACS) you can implement the Push Notification.

It is the simplest and reliable one. Follow  below tutorial for ACS Push Notification implementation on Android and iOS

**Android :**
http://www.titaniumtutorial.com/2012/06/appcelerator-cloud-push-notification-in.html

**iOS :**
http://blog.teemusk.com/2012/05/building-server-push-notifications-with-appcelerator-titanium-cloud/comment-page-1

Hope it helps someone